# CSS - Unable to align images horizontally in 3s

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Trying to align images/contacts horizontally in 3 (wide) x however many (long). Currently the appearance is step like and not horizontal.

Used the below code and switched out `float: left;` for `display: inline-block;` and some others, the structure remains as it 'step like'.

Any ideas how to correct this or if there is something very awry in the code?

index.html.erb

```
<html>

<head></head>
<style>

body {margin:20px; }

.polaroid {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 180px;
}

.polaroid:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 27px;
}

.work {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:5px 4px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div>
<%if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<%end%>
</div>

<% if @contacts.any? %>
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
<div class="polaroid">
  <div class="container">
  <%= link_to image_tag(contact.image.url(:thumb), :class=>"work" ), contact_path(contact) %>
  <h3><%=contact.firstname%> <%=contact.surname%></h3>
  <%=contact.email%><br />
  <%=contact.phone%>
</div>
</div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%end%>
<%else%>
  No contacts yet!
<%end%>

<br />
<br />
  <%= link_to 'Add a contact', new_contact_path%>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top parent (`.polaroid`) has a fixed width of 180px and thus the images wrap under each other because that width is not wide enough to contain 3 images, I recommend removing it UNLESS you want the images to be 33.33% of that fixed width.

**No defined widths example:**

```css
body {margin:20px; }

.polaroid {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.polaroid:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 27px;
}

.work {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding:5px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Image width relative to parent (33.33%) example:**

```css
body {margin:20px; }

.polaroid {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 180px;
}

.polaroid:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 27px;
}

.work {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding:5px 4px;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
    <img class="work" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional Notes:

- `Width`/`Height` properties in CSS must have values with a **unit**, you wrote: `height: 100;` that is wrong, it has to be `100px` or `100%` for example.
- Try to provide compiled HTML instead of .ERB

Comment: Updated with % value. Its still not aligned and is step like. In your code snippet you have `<img class="work` 3 times but the code `<% if @contacts.any? %>
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %> ` runs over each contact in the database and then `<%= link_to image_tag(contact.image.url(:thumb), :class=>"work" ), contact_path(contact) %>
  <h3><%=contact.firstname%> <%=contact.surname%></h3>
  <%=contact.email%><br />
  <%=contact.phone%>` runs over each contacts info. Hence why container and polaroid are around this.

Comment: Ok I see you are adding additional tags (h3 and <br>) these are block elements and they wrap other elements under them, please provide a compiled html for me to help you better. you may share a live demo or create a jsfiddle

Comment: wow removing the <br> has done it THEY ALIGN! Tks. Is there a way so only 3 images appear on each horizontal line?